# Why can putStrLn seemingly change the expected type in the IO monad?

Tags: haskell

I have the following simple function based on csv-conduit, and it is calling a custom `catMaybes` implementation for `Vector`s.

```
retrieveSmaXtec :: IO (Vector SxRecord)
retrieveSmaXtec = do
  rows <- sourceFile "unordered.csv"
    .| intoCSV defCSVSettings
    .| sinkVector
    & runConduitRes
  putStrLn $ show $ size rows  -- DEBUG
  putStrLn $ show $ size $ (fmap fromRow rows) -- DEBUG
  rows & fmap fromRow & catMaybes & return
```

If I remove the two lines with `putStrLn`, everything typechecks, though there does seem to be some problem with the code - though unit tests indicate `fromRow` is working correctly, I still seem to get an empty Vector back when I know I should not. I mention that only because it may be related. My actual question is why, when I add the `putStrLn` calls, I get the error:

```
src/FDS/Data/SmaXtec.hs:64:25: error:                                                                                                       
    * Couldn't match type `Map k0 (Maybe SxRecord)'                                                                                         
                     with `Vector (Maybe SxRecord)'                                                                                         
      Expected type: Map k0 (Maybe SxRecord) -> Vector SxRecord                                                                             
        Actual type: Vector (Maybe SxRecord) -> Vector SxRecord                                                                             
    * In the second argument of `(&)', namely `catMaybes'                                                                                   
      In the first argument of `(&)', namely                                                                                                
        `rows & fmap fromRow & catMaybes'                                                                                                   
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: rows & fmap fromRow & catMaybes & return                                                                   
    * Relevant bindings include                                                                                                             
        rows :: Map k0 (MapRow Text)                                                                                                        
          (bound at src/FDS/Data/SmaXtec.hs:58:3)                                                                                           
   |                                                                                                                                        
64 |   rows & fmap fromRow & catMaybes & return                                                                                             
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

**Update:** As hinted in the comments, `size` was not the function I was looking for. I needed `Data.Vector.length`.

Comment: What type do you think `rows` is?  Is that type in agreement with `size`?  If so, add that signature to your `sourceFile ... :: IO _type_` line.  Then you should see that, even without the  `putStrLn`, GHC complains about a type error.  Consider the implications.

Comment: Likely, without the `putStrLn`, GHC is inferring the type of `rows` from its other uses, in particular from the fact that the returned type depends on the type of `rows`. Adding the `putStrLn` provides another option for type inference, e.g. "`rows`'s type must be such that `size rows` makes sense". This makes `rows` be assigned the `Map` type, only to trigger a type error later on. Adding an explicit type signature to `rows` (as suggested in the comment above) should make the type error more clear.

Comment: Thanks - funny how the thought process resulted in my not realizing the issue. I thought, well if `size` isn't right, I'll get an immediate type error. Forgetting that type errors in Haskell can be a bit lazy and not show up immediately at the place of origin.

Comment: Type errors can always be blamed on at least two locations.  Here we have the possibility size is wrong on the type of the argument or the possibility source file... Is wrong on the type of its result.

Comment: FYI, I think you can just say `print` instead of `putStrLn . show`. I don't think it has any bearing on your problem.